# Transferring data into a reporting database

Tags: sql, xml, database, reporting

We have a relational database with data.  Currently the queries take to long for reporting, so we would like to use that data in a reporting database.

I want to analyze the queries that we use, run the queries at night and put the un normalized into tables that are read only.  I do not believe that there are enough queries to necessitate a data mart.

My boss wants to write everything into xml packages and then whatever database we design, we will read in the xml files.

Like every person on earth, I think that my way is right.  But, I have been wrong before. Can I get some advice and the pluses and minuses of each method?

Answer (score 0):

This question is mostly opnion based, but reading from XML is pretty slow and very memory intensive, so i believe that creating a reporting database would be better, of course there are donwsides like that the unormalized database will ocuppy more space, but i think that with a good design it may work fairly well.